# How can I make an image blink in racket language using a frame counter?

Tags: racket, imaging

The following procedure is in a racket radar simulator for a flight simulator it displays objects that are locking on your aircraft as an ellipse, we need to get the ellipse to blink (appear and reappear periodically). Using a frame counter, or not, how can this be scripted?

```
(define rwr-tracking
  (let ([p (new dc-path%)])
  (send p ellipse 0 0 400 400)
  p)
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to get you started:

```
#lang racket
(define (redraw-radar)
  (sleep 0.5)  ; 0.5 seconds 
  (displayln "Drawing")
  (flush-output)
  (redraw-radar))

(thread redraw-radar)
```

A new thread is created to the redrawing.
The thread waits, redraws, and, loops.